# FTP file transfer on Windows platform using ANSI C?

Tags: c, windows, ftp

I have a known shared folder on another Windows PC and i have to transfer files using my ANSI C program to that shared folder using an FTP connection. I need some directions - please guide me.

Comment: It is shared folder, just copy the file.

Comment: @nobugz, I don't think your comment is specific to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI C standard does not include any networking library. If you can use 3rd party libraries, then you need something [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or some other C networking library or to create an FTP client from ground up using [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you should be careful not to confuse a shared folder and an FTP server: on Windows, the 2 have different meanings (a shared folder uses the SMB protocol, aka Samba).

For FTP transfert, you should use WinINet (which is part of the Windows SDK). This library defines a set of functions for retrieving data from the internet as well as uploading data, and support the FTP and HTTP protocols.

specifically, you need to call `InternetOpenUrl()` or `InternetConnect()` to open the connection, `FtpSetCurrentDirectory()` to navigate to the destination directory, then `FtpPutFile()` to upload the file. finally, use `InternetCloseHandle()` to close the connection.

have a look at [the WinINet documentation about FTP sessions on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384180%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).